# "System Update Available" after already sideloaded Oreo

Tags: side-loading, 8.0-oreo

I recently sideloaded Oreo onto my Nexus 5X, and everything went smoothly. However, today I received a "System Update Available" notification to "upgrade" to Android 8.0. I'm a bit confused; if I go through with this update, is it any different to what I sideloaded? And even if it is, is it better that I go through with it so that e.g. my phone believes that I have indeed upgraded?

Comment: Odds are its Sept security update.

Comment: It described itself as the update to Oreo though, and it was a 947 MB download.

Comment: I mean I wouldn't be to worried about it. Way their ota works it compares some build id's and doesn't mess with data partition. I'm assuming you used googles factory image fully and not some half flash, which case no one would know  if something will go wrong except you.

Comment: Okay, I'll chalk it up to the fine details of how their update system works and assume they've just not implemented it efficiently for this scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it'll be a new build update, but simply prefaced with the android Oreo blurb.

I had exactly the same thing... And after updating compared the previous sideloaded build to the new one (even though it had been the sept 2017 security updates originally sideloaded) and the build number had bumped up.